# Compilation of Python 3.5.1 fails on Solaris 8 sparc

Tags: python, compilation, solaris

When I try to compile the python from source on Solaris 8. I getting the following error

> Modules/_localemodule.o: In function PyIntl_gettext':
>   Modules/_localemodule.o(.text+0xb60): undefined reference to
>   libintl_gettext' Modules/_localemodule.o: In function
>   PyIntl_dgettext': Modules/_localemodule.o(.text+0xba8): undefined
>   reference to libintl_dgettext' Modules/_localemodule.o: In function
>   PyIntl_dcgettext': Modules/_localemodule.o(.text+0xbf8): undefined
>   reference to libintl_dcgettext' Modules/_localemodule.o: In function
>   PyIntl_textdomain': Modules/_localemodule.o(.text+0xc38): undefined
>   reference to libintl_textdomain' Modules/_localemodule.o: In function
>   PyIntl_bindtextdomain': Modules/_localemodule.o(.text+0xcec):
>   undefined reference to libintl_bindtextdomain'
>   Modules/_localemodule.o: In function PyIntl_bind_textdomain_codeset':
>   Modules/_localemodule.o(.text+0xde0): undefined reference to
>   libintl_bind_textdomain_codeset' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [Programs/_freeze_importlib] Error 1

The steps that I followed :

```
 CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
 export CPPFLAGS
 LD_OPTIONS='-L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib'
 export LD_OPTIONS
 LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib'
 export LDFLAGS
 CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc OPT="-O2" ./configure  --prefix=/opt/soe/local/Python-3.5.1
```

Comment: Can you try compiling with `--disable-nls`?

Comment: # CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc OPT="-O2" ./configure  --prefix=/opt/soe/local/Python-3.5.1 --disable-nls

configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-nls

Comment: Do you have `libintl.so` available?

Comment: for d in /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /lib; do ls -l $d/libintl.*; done
-rw-r--r--   1 root     other     584940 Sep  3 10:46 /usr/local/lib/libintl.a
-rw-r--r--   1 root     other        913 Sep  3 10:46 /usr/local/lib/libintl.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     other       2484 Feb 19 11:19 /usr/local/lib/libintl.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     other       2484 Feb 18 06:21 /usr/local/lib/libintl.so.1
/usr/lib/libintl.*: No such file or directory
/lib/libintl.*: No such file or directory

Comment: @pydev Can you please tell me how you got python-2.5 compiled on solaris 8? I'm trying to compile it for two days now.